# Google Apps Script: Salesforce OAuth2 integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, salesforce, google-oauth

I am trying to connect to Salesforce using OAuth2 in Google Sheets Add-on.

```
var url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' +
           clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri + '&display=popup' + 
           '&scope=full' + '&prompt=login';
```

Where the `redirectUri` is another Google Apps Script WebApp URL.

Now I need to share the `code` returned by Salesforce to my Google Sheets Add-on and not able to find a solution for it.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do authentication.

Any help or suggestion would be great.

Comment: Hi @Jayakrishnan, there is an officially recommended (and very robust) OAuth 2.0 library for Google Apps Script which you should [use](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) - there is also a sample of how to create the flow with Salesforce, so it should be easy to do

Comment: @OlegValter, it redirects to the new tab. This is my exact requirement:
1) I want to open the OAuth2 window as a child window.
2) Close it automatically after successful login.
3) Send the code to Google Sheets addon.
Can you please help me.

Comment: Hi @Jayakrishnan, isn't this what 3-legged OAuth is about? You don't need to negotiate the code exchange yourself - the token is saved during `authCallback` cbk (called after user grants / denies access) execution when you call `handleCallback()` method. You can autoclose the window with `setTimeout( () => window.close(), msOfDelay )` in your html template. After that, you can access latest token via `getAccessToken()` anytime (just be sure that OAuth service is the same / copy of the one used for auth). If you have more q - I can dive in detail in an answer

Comment: @OlegValter, OAuth2.0 library opens a new window, is it possible to show it as a child window in the same tab? If possible can you give me an answer in detail

Comment: @OlegValter, I am able to open a child window using the sample code from the link (https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) you gave. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Hi @Jayakrishnan, glad that you resolved the issue! Just to make sure - you were opening it via `window.open()` method, right? Iframing and loading in the same context shouldn't be possible (and judjing from the sample code, it uses the same technique)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

No, you cannot open a child window to be loaded in the same context in Editor Add-ons.

**Explanation**

As Google Apps Script uses security sandbox to sanitize user application content, you won't be able to utilize `<iframe>` or same-window resource loading. Although you can load the target resource in the same window in a WebApp, you can't in Editor Add-ons (`allow-top-navigation` for the `sandbox` attribute is not set when in context of Editor Add-on).

If this is ok with you, I would suggest setting `width` and `height`, as well as `top` and `left` properties to center or move the window close to sidebar + using `window.open()`, optionally with a fallback to link if popups are blocked. This will at least keep quality of UX relatively intact.

**References**

If you want to learn more about what restrictions and practices are in place:

1. `HTMLService` restrictions [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)
2. `IFRAME` mode migration [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe)